# How to check running job on self-hosted Azure DevOps Agent on Linux via bash

Tags: linux, azure, devops, azure-agent

I have installed the Azure DevOps agent on my Linux Ubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) machine - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops.

Now I want to write a script, which will check if there is some job (pipeline) running on an agent.

Is it possible to somehow check whether there is a job running on the agent via bash on Linux, where is the agent installed? Without API calls to Azure DevOps.

Comment: Try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#status): `sudo ./svc.sh status`. It need `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by reading the status of the agent service:

Go to folder where you installed the agent and run -

`./svc.sh status | tail -n1 | grep -c -e "Running"`

1. Get the agent status
2. Get the last line
3. Check if the last line contains the word `Running`. If not, the return code will be 0, and you know, that there is not any job currently running on Agent. Otherwise, the return code of the command will be >=1.